# WirelessSettings activity is not found on Android SDK 3.0

Tags: android, settings, fragment

I'm porting an application to SDK 3.0.
I have already modified the Settings to use the new Fragment feature available in PreferenceActivity.

The problem I have now is that the following configuration I had in the settings.xml does not work any more:

```
    <PreferenceScreen
        xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        android:key="@string/mykey"
        android:summary="@string/musummary"
        android:title="@string/mytitle" >

        <intent
            android:action="android.intent.action.MAIN"
            android:targetClass="com.android.settings.WirelessSettings"
            android:targetPackage="com.android.settings" />
    </PreferenceScreen>
```

com.android.settings.WirelessSettings is not found. Do you know why?

My first guess is that now that activity does not exist any more and was replaced by a fragment.
The problem is that I can't find how to call this fragment.
Do you know how to embed the standard WirelessSettings Fragment in my application?

Thank you

Comment: I have also tried:            <intent android:action="android.provider.settings.Settings.ACTION_WIFI_SE‌​TTINGS"/>

Comment: with that intent I get: android.content.ActivityNotFoundException: No Activity found to handle Intent {...

Comment: I should add that I'm running the application on the Motorola Xoom.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

OK finally I found the correct version. This works:

```
        <intent 
            android:action="android.settings.WIRELESS_SETTINGS"/>
```

Comment: So the action is android.provider.Settings.ACTION_WIRELESS_SETTINGS that is a string with a value ="android.settings.WIRELESS_SETTINGS". I'm using the value directly in the xml. Maybe not the best way

Answer (score 0):

> com.android.settings.WirelessSettings is not found. Do you know why?

They either elected to rename the class or make it be not exported. You should not have been using this in the first place -- any references to `com.android` are a really bad idea, as they are not part of the Android SDK.

> Do you know how to embed the standard WirelessSettings Fragment in my application?

You can't embed fragments from other applications in your own application.

> I have also tried:  with that intent I get: android.content.ActivityNotFoundException: No Activity found to handle Intent {...

I can tell you that this works on a XOOM:

```
startActivity(new Intent(Settings.ACTION_WIFI_SETTINGS));
```

Your action string is wrong -- replace `settings.Settings` with just `Settings`. Try that and see if it helps. If not, perhaps there is something peculiar about using `<intent>` in preference XML -- I've never used it. Regardless, `Settings.ACTION_WIFI_SETTINGS` is the proper way to refer to this particular portion of Settings.

Comment: I don't think that "android.provider.settings.Settings.ACTION_WIFI_SE‌​TTINGS" is wrong: "android.provider.settings" is the package "Settings" is the class and ACTION_WIFI_SE‌​TTINGS the const to be used. I have also tried to explictly specify the package in the intent tag but it did not help

Comment: @user38: `android.provider` is the package. There is no `android.provider.settings` package in Android. http://developer.android.com/reference/android/provider/Settings.html

Comment: I tried:<intent android:action="android.provider.settings.Settings.ACTION_WIFI_SE‌​TTINGS" android:targetPackage="android.provider.settings"/> as I said it did not help

Comment: @user38: Delete the extra `settings.`. Delete the `android:targetPackage`. Just use `<intent android:action="android.provider.Settings.ACTION_WIFI_SE‌​TTINGS" />`.

Comment: I'll try that but I found the Const in that way with Eclipse's help